# node.js serving up HTML documents in server directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

So I have a pretty simple question, at the moment my server file and HTML documents all live in the same directory. However, I've realised this has lead to quite an annoying problem. If I user were to type:

```
http://localhost:3000/HTML/homepage.html
```

The server serves them the HTML document, where usually they'd have to go through sign in, and have their session ID verified before they could access the homepage.

Is there any way to deny access to files held in the server directory?

Example of how my code currently runs:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var session = require('express-session')

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/HTML/signin'));
});

app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;


    if (email!="" || password != ""){
        req.session.sessID = email //using email for example purposes

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            success: true //the client then catches the JSON, and will redirect to http://localhost:3000/homepage
        }));
    }
}

app.get('/homepage', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.sessID == undefined){
        res.send("You must login first!")
    }else{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/HTML/homepage.html'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Express JS?

Comment: We need to see the relevant server-side code you are using.  Yes, there are lots of ways to solve this problem, but the appropriate method depends upon what code you are currently using.

Comment: @jfriend00 Added some example code, hope it makes sense.

Comment: @JoeyGuerra Yes, I am.

Comment: are you using a static html middleware?

Comment: @JoeyGuerra I don't think so, just sending the file using a GET function when they arrive at the URL.

Comment: But I don't see any code above that is setup to handle the /HTML route. I would expect to see something like app.use('/HTML', function(req, res){}) if you haven't setup a static file handler as middleware, specifying 'HTML' as the folder to use to pull those files.

Comment: @JoeyGuerra Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie, I've included everything which I call at the start of my code. I don't have any functions which handle the /HTML route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

This tells express to serve ANY file it can find on your hard drive from the app directory on down.  This is not advisable.  This will even serve up your private server source code files if the right path is entered into the browser.

You should distinguish between your static files and your dynamically handled routes and you should make sure there is no possibility of conflict between them.

A common design is to designate a separate directory on your hard drive for static HTML files (not your app directory) and then set up express static routing to there.  And, make sure that none of your dynamic routes will ever be satisfied with the static routing.

For example, if your static HTML files are in a sub-directory `HTML` which is below your `__dirname` directory, then you can do this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "HTML")));
```

And, then make sure none of your dynamic HTML files such as homepage.html are in that directory (put them somewhere else that `express.static()` will not ever see).

---

If you don't actually want the user to be able to see anything except your custom routes, then get rid of the `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` line entirely and just create custom routes for each page you are serving.

Comment: Okay, this has been helpful. I understand that using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "HTML")));` means that a user can't access any file outside of this folder. But this then begs the question of how I serve the page, as now I can't simply do `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/HTML/homepage.html'));`, because it is no longer in this directory. Can you give me an example of  how I would serve the dynamic HTML file?

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused - You put your dynamic HTML files in a different directory that is not accessible to `express.static()` and you use the path to that other directory with your `res.sendFile()`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Solved by putting `res.sendFile('homepage.html', { root: path.join(__dirname) });`. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused - And make sure that there is no copy of `homepage.html` in the HTML sub-directory.  And, you don't need the `path.join(__dirname)`.  You can just refer to `__dirname` directly in your `res.sendFile()` line.

Comment: @jfriend00 nice job getting to the point quickly and concisely.